# when changing a text of a text box in asynchronous events, why should the passing argument be in square brackets?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I don't understand why the subroutine syntax is like this in:

```
Private Sub SetText(ByVal [text] As String)
    ' InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
    ' calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
    ' If these threads are different, it returns true.
    If Me.textBox1.InvokeRequired Then
        Dim d As New SetTextCallback(AddressOf SetText)
        Me.Invoke(d, New Object() {[text]})
    Else
        Me.textBox1.Text = [text]
    End If
End Sub
```

The original article link is:
[Thread Safe calls on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728%28v=vs.80%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` is a [language keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t.aspx). It's use in conjunction with [`Option Compare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172930.aspx)

It's not a *reserved* word, because there's only a limited use for it, so you have to look down in the 2nd table, but it is still a keyword. That means you want to enclose it in square brackets to prevent the compiler from treating like the keyword.